# Special characters (i.e. '...' character) causing query to fail

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I am not sure what character set this character '...' belongs to. However, in some cases, users copy and paste data in to the note field of an application I am working on. The note contents contains this special characters and causes the insert / update query to fail.

I was wondering if there is a string function to detect and remove this special character (along with other unwanted characters from this character set), while maintaining all other special characters ?

Example:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES ("… hello … world!")';
mysqli_query($conn, $query); //nothing is inserted
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code are you using to process this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I am using PHP to code and mysqli_query for the db commands.

Comment: "Causes query to fail" is not specific enough. **How** does it cause it to fail? Any errors?

Comment: What is the code you are using? You say PHP, but what is the actual code? Show us. A MySQLi database, OK. But what are the settings in the table? InnoDB engine? Character set?

Comment: No errors, just doesn't insert. innoDB engine, utf-8 character set.

Comment: Good. Now, paste the (relevant) PHP code in here.

Comment: Where is the rest of the query? You know...the `INSERT INTO` or `SELECT`, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, what Jay said. This makes no sense. You are not doing an insert. Where is the `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (value2, value2)`?

Comment: My apologies, I have the complete query in the code, just made an error above, fixed it.

Comment: Those characters shouldn't cause an insert failure, the database doesn't care about them. What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would consider accepting a wider set of characters. (You just need to remember to escape the characters properly.) To strip out certain characters just isn't user friendly, and using UTF-8 just seems limited.

If you really want to strip out UTF-8 characters, you can use

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x19-\x7F)]*/','', $string);
```

as described [here](http://hawkee.com/snippet/4224/).

---

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$string = "a bc…de f";
echo preg_replace('/[^(\x19-\x7F)]*/','', $string); 
?>
```

**Output:**

```
a bcde f
```

---

Finally, you need to escape your input:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x19-\x7F)]*/','', $string);
$string = mysqli_escape_string($string);
$query = 'INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (' . $string . ')';
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. These are the exact characters that are causing the failure: http://www.forlang.wsu.edu/help/keyboards.asp. The preg_replace above isn't allowing a successful insert either. When I tried a preg_replace for alphanumeric characters only, it insert successfully, however.

Comment: Added an example. Isn't the ellipsis removed when you do it?

Comment: Hey aioobe, it does remove the ellipsis, however, it also removes whitespace which we are trying to keep, linebreaks, etc. Without the preg_replace the whitespace remains.

Comment: Updated answer: Changed from `\x20` to `\x19` to allow `\x20` which corresponds to space.

Comment: Thanks aioobe, did not help though. Linebreaks are still removed.

Comment: so use [^(\x19-\x7F\x0A)] ?

Answer (score 0):

Before solving your problem, you shouldnt insert raw input into your database.

What you should do is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$string = mysqli_escape_string($conn, "… hello … world!");
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

error_reporting will show you raw errors on screen and escaping the string will:

a) Avoid SQL injections.

b) Insert the record even if it has special chars.

Now, if you need to remove those special chars use something like:

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

before escaping it.